# return the Non IQueryable value via linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

in an specific case I'm writing this method to return a post by category Id :

```
public Post GetPostByCategory(Guid categoryId)
        {
            var query= _siteContext.Posts.Where(p => p.Category.Id == categoryId)
                                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationDate);
            return query;//Error 
        }
```

I just want to return the query , query must by a type of Post , what can I do ??

I don't want to return the list of post like this

```
 public IList<Post> GetPostByCategory(Guid categoryId)
            {
                var query= _siteContext.Posts.Where(p => p.Category.Id == categoryId)
                                        .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationDate);
                return query.tolist(); 
            }
```

I have done somthine like this before via Nhibernate :

```
  public int TotalPostsForCategory(string categorySlug)
        {
          return _session.Query<Post>()
                        .Where(p => p.Published && p.Category.UrlSlug.Equals(categorySlug))
                        .Count();
        }
```

How can I do that with Entity Framework???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `First` or `Single` like this:

```
public Post GetPostByCategory(Guid categoryId)
{
  var query= _siteContext.Posts.Where(p => p.Category.Id == categoryId)
                         .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationDate);
  return query.First();
}
```

or

```
public Post GetPostByCategory(Guid categoryId)
{
  var query= _siteContext.Posts.Where(p => p.Category.Id == categoryId)
                         .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationDate);
  return query.Single();
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348657.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx

Comment: Would it not be better to use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` so you don't throw `ArgumentNullException` or `InvalidOperationException`?

Comment: It depends on the use case, and whether you except null

Comment: Ah, then your return `object` should be `Nullable<Post>`.

Answer (score 2):

You must use the [FirstOrDefault()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb340482.aspx) extension method to return only the first element:

```
public Post GetPostByCategory(Guid categoryId)
{
    var firstPost = _siteContext.Posts
                                .Where(p => p.Category.Id == categoryId)
                                .OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationDate)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
    return firstPost;
}
```

The FirstOrDefault will be replace by a TOP 1 in the SQL query.
The query should look likes this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 p.*
FROM Posts p
WHERE p.CategoryId = categoryId
ORDER BY p.CreationDate DESC
```